# Should we use the Date Object in java?

Tags: java, date

Should we use de java.util.Date object in java?
It has so many Deprecated methods that is a little anoying to have to use a complex method to something that should be so simples.

I am using something stupid to emulate getDate() like:

```
    public static int toDayMonth (Date dt)
{
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
    String day = df.format(dt);
    return Integer.parseInt(day);
}
```

It has to be better way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) for each method says what it's been replaced by. To emulate `getDate()`, use:

```
Calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
```

**EDIT**: Full example:

```
public static int toDayMonth (Date dt) {
    Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
    c.setTime(dt);
    return c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have seen that line "Calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)".
But how to use it? Where do i put the date object?

Comment: you have to set the date of the Calendar object.  calendar.setDate(date)

Answer (score 5):

Might be a matter of preference, but I use [**Joda Time**](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

Looking at the [`DateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) API from Joda Time,
[`DateTime#dayOfMonth`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#dayOfMonth%28%29) might be what you were looking for.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
// no args in constructor returns current date and time
DateTime.Property day = dt.dayOfMonth();
System.out.println(day.get()); // prints '27'
```

Comment: I think this is a good idea, as last I heard Joda Time was being considered for inclusion in Java 7.  I may be mistaken though

Comment: @Phil: I have read somewhere that they weren't going to port over Joda Time into Java 7, but to try to learn from it.

Answer (score 3):

The Java Date class is notorious for being confusing and clunky.  I'd recommend looking at the popular "Joda Time" library:

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

No, you shouldn't really use java.util.Date anymore.

[GregorianCalendar](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) is an alternative that you can use:

```
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JUNE);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 27);
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2010);
```

Comment: I'd rather make use of `Calendar#getInstance()`. The factory will return a locale dependent Calendar.